# Working on a .bat script that is meant to take the PCs name and change it, but unsure how. Any Advice?

Tags: batch-file

I just learned a bit of scripting today, and want to know if it's possible to change a computer's name using a .bat file.

Here is what I have right now:

```
@echo off

::print original PC name
echo The systems current name is %COMPUTERNAME%

::prompt user for new PC name (id)
set /p id="Enter the ID: "
echo ID entered is %id%

::apply new name
netdom.exe renamecomputer %COMPUTERNAME% /newname: %id%

::confirm changes
echo The systems current name is %COMPUTERNAME%

pause
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried reading the `%COMPUTERNAME%` variable from a different cmd.exe instance, or directly from the registry. I'm assuming that it is still outputting the same name as it did earlier in the code.

Comment: No I haven't tried those, and yes the name remained unchanged.

Comment: If memory serves me correctly a reboot is always required after a computer name change for the change to take affect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using this:

```
@echo off

::print original PC name
echo The systems current name is %COMPUTERNAME%

::prompt user for new PC name (id)
set /p id="Enter the ID: "
echo ID entered is %id%

::apply new name
REG ADD HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ComputerName\ComputerName /v ComputerName /t REG_SZ /d %id% /f >nul 
WMIC computersystem where caption='%COMPUTERNAME%' rename %id% >nul 

::confirm changes
echo The systems current name is %COMPUTERNAME%

pause
```